# Linked text dissapear when in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, simplexml, shortcode

Using shortcodes in my WordPress theme works fine, everything until I add a hyperlink to some word or part of the existing text. When linked, that part of the text simply disappear!
Looking at the page source, I can only see empty div tags `<div></div>`

Here is the part of the tabs shortcode generator source currently used in theme:

```
    function cs_shortcode_pb_tabs($atts, $content="") {
    global $tab_counter;
    $tab_counter++;
    $content = str_replace("[cs_tab_item", "<cs_tab_item", $content);
    $content = str_replace("[/cs_tab_item]", "</cs_tab_item>", $content);
    $content = str_replace('tabs="tabs"]', ">", $content);
    $content = str_replace("<br />", "", $content);
    $content = str_replace("<p>", "", $content);
    $content = str_replace("</p>", "", $content);
    $content = "<tab>". $content . "</tab>";
    $html = "";
    $tabs_count = 0;
        $html .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
            $xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
                foreach ( $xmlObject as $node ){
                    $tabs_count++;
                    if($tabs_count==1) $tab_active=" active"; else $tab_active="";
                    $html .= '<li class="'.$tab_active.'"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#'.str_replace(" ","",$node["title"].$tab_counter).'">'.$node["title"].'</a></li>';
                }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        $html .= '<div class="tab-content">';
        $tabs_count = 0;
            foreach ( $xmlObject as $node ){
                $tabs_count++;
                if($tabs_count==1) $tab_active=" active"; else $tab_active="";
                $html .= '<div class="tab-pane '.$tab_active.'" id="'.str_replace(" ","",$node["title"].$tab_counter).'">'.$node.'</div>';
            }
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html = '<div class="tabs-sectn">'.$html.'</div>';
    return do_shortcode($html).'<div class="clear"></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'cs_tab', 'cs_shortcode_pb_tabs' );
```

Please note that `.$node["title"].` (line 18) works just fine - it displays tag name, but on the other hand `.$node.` (line 26) works fine until the link is given to some part of the text.
Platform used is WordPress 3.5. Plugins disabled, and without CSS conflicts such as `display:none`

Comment: Seems like you have nested shortcodes in the `$content`. Paste some example `$content` please that would allow me to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 26 you echo your node direct by `echo $node`; (first add it to a string but echo this). So i expect you node contains some data, something like:

```
<node>
<title>title</title>
Text content here echoed as node.
</node>
```

If you add a link to this plain text values, this link will be read as child node (a) an so not echoed. Try prevent this try to parse your link with for example `htmlspecialchars()`.

example:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
   Content of a node. " . htmlspecialchars('<a href="http://php.net/">PHP</a>') . "
 </movie>
  <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
   Content of a node 2 <a href='http://php.net/'>PHP</a>
 </movie>
</movies>";

$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ( $xmlObject as $node ){
  echo $node;
  echo $node->a;
}
```

as you see in the second node the link become a child node. You can echo this with `$node->a` which only print the content (link text in your case).

Comment: Yes, I think that Your idea is correct. I have tried something similar and achieved a partial solution since other stuff involved get stacked. One problem leading to another and vice versa, so I decided to involve additional plugin. I don't like using unnecessary plugins, but I didn't had too many choices at the moment.

Thanks Bass!